# Zero-centering a kernel matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I'm trying to implement the algorithm in [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6072216) paper. As you can see at page 4, it is explained how to 0-centering a `pxp` symmetric Kernel matrix `K` as (where `e` are vector of ones):

[image]

However, in the matlab code provided this formula is expressed as:

```
K = K - (1/p)*(K*ones(p,1))*ones(1,p) - (1/p)*ones(p,1)*(ones(1,p)*K) + (1/p^2)*sum(sum(K))
```

As you can see, in the third term the matlab formula has an extra `K`. My question is: which one is the correct one?

Comment: the second one, which is a symmetric matrix : $K - \frac{K e e^T}{p} - \frac{ e e^T K}{p}  + C\frac{ e e^T}{ p} $ where $C = \frac{1}{p}\sum_{i,j} K_{i,j}$

Comment: Wow, seems we found an error in a paper here :D If you'll post it as an answer I'll chose it